# How to fix libudev memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, debian, usb

I'm implementing a libudev based monitoring code for USB devices under the hidraw driver. I've implemented the standard example from the web and checked for memory leaks with valgrind and gdb.

```
/*******************************************
 libudev example.

 This example prints out properties of
 each of the hidraw devices. It then
 creates a monitor which will report when
 hidraw devices are connected or removed
 from the system.

 This code is meant to be a teaching
 resource. It can be used for anyone for
 any reason, including embedding into
 a commercial product.

 The document describing this file, and
 updated versions can be found at:
    http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

 Alan Ott
 Signal 11 Software
 2010-05-22 - Initial Revision
 2010-05-27 - Monitoring initializaion
              moved to before enumeration.
*******************************************/
```

I was unhappy to find that some libudev functions that are not supposed to allocate memory are leaking. I traced this by exiting (after all objects are unreff'ed) at differrent points and looking at the valgrind report. Specifically This code leaks:

```
int main (void)
{
struct udev *udev;
struct udev_enumerate *enumerate;
struct udev_list_entry *devices, *dev_list_entry;
struct udev_device *dev, *devParent;
struct udev_monitor *mon;
int fd;

/* Create the udev object */
udev = udev_new();
if (!udev) 
{
    printf("Can't create udev\n");
    exit(1);
}
/* This section sets up a monitor which will report events when
    blah blah....
   "hidraw" devices. */

/* Set up a monitor to monitor hidraw devices */
mon = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink(udev, "udev");
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(mon, "hidraw", NULL);
udev_monitor_enable_receiving(mon);
/* Get the file descriptor (fd) for the monitor.
   This fd will get passed to select() */
fd = udev_monitor_get_fd(mon);

/* Create a list of the devices in the 'hidraw' subsystem. */
enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(udev);
udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "hidraw");
if (1)
{
    // leak debug block
    udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
    udev_monitor_unref(mon);
    udev_unref(udev);
    return 0;
}
udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enumerate);
devices = udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate);
/* For each item enumerated, print out its information.
```

Here is the valgrind output:

```
==11424== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11424==     in use at exit: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==11424==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 10 frees, 28,086 bytes allocated
==11424== 
==11424== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11424==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11424==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11424==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11424==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==11424==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11424== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

If I place the "leak debug block" one line prior to its above position valgrind exits with a clean result of 0 bytes leaked.
If I advance the block one line down the code the next function increases the leak size and components:

```
==14262==     in use at exit: 8,192 bytes in 2 blocks
==14262==   total heap usage: 45 allocs, 43 frees, 150,907 bytes allocated
==14262== 
==14262== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14262==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14262==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14262==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14262==    still reachable: 8,192 bytes in 2 blocks
==14262==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14262== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

It gets worse after the next line and it is of concern because my code needs to run over years and such leaks can accumulate unchecked.

Any suggestions why it happens and how to keep it under control?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are a few minor edits I wish to make ( you have an open paren and an open quote with no closes in your text ), but it's too few characters for me to make the changes. Additionally have you determined which line is causing the leak? I couldn't figure out if you found that yet.

Comment: You really should list the function(s) that are supposedly leaking.   You describe your code i.e. "one line prior", "advance the block one line down", etc. but that doesn't state up front which function is leaking.  Is the code you posted the "correct" code?  Is it already "advanced one line down"?  Please clarify by posting the non-working code, or specify that the code you posted is the non-working version.

Comment: @Jeff  Quotations and Parenthesis corrected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The first line that leaks is `code` udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "hidraw");          The valgrind dump is:            ==20471== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20471==     in use at exit: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==20471==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 10 frees, 28,086 bytes allocated
==20471== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.5)
==20471==    by 0x108BAA: main (in /home/pi/projects/eclipse/testUSB/udevHidraw)
==20471== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20471==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks

Answer (score 3):

Seems that these memory leaks related to the hash tables as reported by valgrind are not a concern see discussion in
https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/issues/405 and a relevant Red Hat bug report at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1280334.